# FTP Issues on MacOS, can't write on the disk

Tags: hard-drive, firewall, ftp

I'm developing a website for a client, but some space of the server we will be used to transfer large files of softwares like Maya Autodesk (my client working with 3D modeling). I'm trying to configure the filezilla on MacOS of my client which did not work correctly. It is possible to upload files, but I can not download anything from server. I checked if it was the firewall that was blocking Filezilla, but it wasn't.

The error message that appears is below:

```
Status:         Resolving address of sl1064.web.hostpoint.ch
Status:         Connecting to 217.26.61.24:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:         Connected
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Status:         Directory listing of "/" successful
Status:         Retrieving directory listing of "/3d_files"...
Status:         Directory listing of "/3d_files" successful
Status:         Resolving address of sl1064.web.hostpoint.ch
Status:         Connecting to 217.26.61.24:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:         Connected
Status:         Starting download of /3d_files/Gallop_2.mov
Command:    CWD /3d_files
Response:   250 OK. Current directory is /3d_files
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/3d_files" is your current location
Error:          Failed to open "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Gallop_2.mov" for writing
Error:          File transfer failed
Status:         Starting download of /3d_files/Gallop_2.mov
Error:          Failed to open "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Gallop_2.mov" for writing
Error:          File transfer failed
Status:         Starting download of /3d_files/Gallop_2.mov
Error:          Failed to open "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Gallop_2.mov" for writing
Error:          File transfer failed
Status:         Disconnected from server
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Does the FTP daemon/client  have write permissions to the folder in question?  That said, you should be using SFTP, or SCP.  FTP is *very* insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP is less used than it was due to security concerns. Do you have/ can you get access to the logs from the host? those will give more information about why the transfers are failing.

If you want a GUI you can connect as a specific user and use Screen Sharing to copy things off and on from that account as long as the host is configured to allow another computer to connect and use apple events. It can be something as simple as a guest account as long as it has a public drop box your client can drop whatever you need in there
press ⌘K to open the network connection.

If you don't care about the gui and are comfortable with the terminal:

- try using ftp from the terminal -ftp will run in verbose mode giving you more information
- try using ssh to connect to the host and use ftp on the host to send you the files